# VB6 POST to a server with content-type form-data doesn't receive the parameters

Tags: post, request, vb6, xmlhttprequest

I trying to do a post request to a server using Content-Type=form-data. This is in VB6 (yes, visual basic6).
The request call is successful, but the server cannot acquire the parameters.

I'm testing with httpbin.org, for simplest.

```
Dim msxml As msxml.XMLHTTPRequest
Dim data As String
Dim boundary As String

Set msxml = New msxml.XMLHTTPRequest


boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"

msxml.Open "POST", "http://httpbin.org/post", False

msxml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;Charset=UTF-8; boundary=" & boundary

data = ""
data = data & boundary & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""param1""" & vbCrLf
data = data & vbCrLf
data = data & "data for param1" & vbCrLf

data = data & boundary & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""param2""" & vbCrLf
data = data & vbCrLf
data = data & "other data for param2" & vbCrLf

data = data & boundary & "--"

msxml.Send data

Debug.Print msxml.responseText
```

The response obtained is:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "es",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "216",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;Charset=UTF-8; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "181.45.250.169",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

As you see, the **"form"** property is empty.

The expected response:

```
"form": {
    "param1": "data for param1",
    "param2": "other data for param2"
},
```

I've already tried with WinHttpRequest and others, always the same result.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why the [tag:vba] tag on a question about [tag:vb6]?

Comment: What was the expected response?

Comment: vba tag, my mistake. i added the expected response.

Comment: You've got your boundary wrong. Check [this post](https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/) how it's done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped me.

Beside the error in the boundary that suggest to me, thing that i tried without success because I was missing the *Content-Type* for the parameters.

Adding the *Content-Type* and the correct boundary string, the post works

```
Dim msxml As msxml.XMLHTTPRequest
Dim data As String
Dim boundary As String

Set msxml = New msxml.XMLHTTPRequest

boundary = "MyCustomBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"

msxml.Open "POST", "http://httpbin.org/post", False

msxml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;Charset=UTF-8; boundary=" & boundary

data = ""
data = data & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""param1""" & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Type: text/plain" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
data = data & "data for param1" & vbCrLf

data = data & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""param2""" & vbCrLf
data = data & "Content-Type: text/plain" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
data = data & "other data for param2" & vbCrLf

data = data & "--" & boundary & "--"

msxml.Send data

Debug.Print msxml.responseText
```

Answer (score 2):

What about changing:

```
boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
```

to:

```
boundary = "WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
```

... instead, and then in the places where it is needed prefix this value with "--" (not "----").

The "--" prefix does not belong here, and you have *two* of them in a row:

```
msxml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;Charset=UTF-8; boundary=" & boundary
```

By doubling up the "--" you appear to have confused yourself.  The hyphens are *not* part of the boundary value.

Answer (score 1):

After this line

```
data = data & "other data for param2" & vbCrLf
```

and before this line

```
msxml.Send data
```

try putting

```
data = data & boundary & "--"
```

to end the form's body in a syntactically valid manner.